# convert "&#xe9;" to "é" in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, utf-8

What is the best way to convert a string will XML entities like `&#xe9;` to => `é`in PHP ?

```
$string = "\xe9"; // é
echo utf8_encode($string );
```

is working great,
but what to do with `&#xe9;`

replace &# per \ then use utf8 ?

Comment: [html_entity_decode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) would do the trick.

Comment: seems to work only on PHP5.4 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2338f4929c669313e91774f97b3fd2f07d4a304e

Answer (score 4):

Prior to PHP 5.4, the encoding defaults to `ISO-8859-1`

So use:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#xe9;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Output for 5.0.0 - 5.5.0beta2 (in UTF-8 encoding)

```
é
```

[Example in 80+ PHP Versions](http://3v4l.org/A7mKa#v500)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

[An IDEone to test with](http://ideone.com/fWCGVw).

Comment: Works only on PHP 5.4 not working on PHP5.3, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2338f4929c669313e91774f97b3fd2f07d4a304e

Comment: @TomPAP You didn't mention any particular PHP version. It works, but it's using the wrong encoding to show it on the page. See Jon's answer how to work around it on 5.3 and earlier if you're using UTF-8.